# Why does declare -p not work unless the name is local?

Tags: bash, global-variables, local-variables, declare

e.g.

```
outer() {
    declare -a array
    inner
}

inner() {
    declare -p array
}

outer
```

It bizarrely doesn't work, though:

```
ryan@DevPC-LX ~/langtest/sh $ ./ar
./ar: line 9: declare: array: not found
ryan@DevPC-LX ~/langtest/sh $
```

I get the same result if I use `declare -ga` instead of `declare -a` to explicitly declare it as global. However, if I first make it local:

```
outer() {
    local array
    declare -a array
    inner
}

inner() {
    declare -p array
}

outer
```

then it works:

```
ryan@DevPC-LX ~/langtest/sh $ ./ar
declare -a array='()'
ryan@DevPC-LX ~/langtest/sh $
```

Why do globals not work but locals do?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this in bash 4.4.11(1) or in 3.2.57(1). Which version are you using?

Comment: @thatotherguy `4.3.11(1)`